# Different sized TabPage items within the same TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a `TabControl` with multiple `TabPage` items.

Is it possible to make one `TabPage` a different size from the rest, while keeping all the tabs within the same control? I'm trying to resize the actual pages themselves, not the tab icons.

Comment: @LarsTech you may know it as a TabControl? I literally just mean a group of tabs all under a single control. I.E. TabControl.add(this.Tab1), TabControl.add(this.Tab2)...etc.

Comment: @GrantWinney you are correct. Normally it wouldn't be the most appealing but I'm making this for purely industrial/experimental purposes at the moment. I'm more seeing if it can be done than actually designing it for mass use. But again, you are very correct.

Comment: You mean a TabControl inside a TabPage?  Resize an individual TabPage?  You would have to resize the TabControl (and any parent container, such as the parent TabControl) when that one tab get's selected.  Resize it again when it gets unselected.  The TabControl has Selecting and Deselecting events you can use.  Not a great user experience otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not a great UI. But thanks for the help! Looks like the answer is posted but thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make one tab larger you can add a bunch of spaces in the tab's Text property until you get to the desired size.

If you want to resize the TabControl for each tab I would add code to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to resize the TabControl based on what tab is selected. Though, I don't know if I recommend this from a UX perspective.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for... I'm looking to resize the actual pages themselves. Not the tabs. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I think I'll also just mark your answer as the correct one so I can end the thread. Thanks for the help!